# Bignum library for Javascript

Tags: library, javascript, math, numerical-analysis

I'm looking for a bignum library for Javascript. Necessary features:

- Ability to manipulate integers from, say, -10<sup>1000</sup> to 10<sup>1000</sup> or better
- Addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, modulus, exponentiation, modular exponentiation
- Conversion between bignums, native numbers, and native strings

Important features:

- Fast operations -- at least [Karatsuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm) multiplication/division
- Number theory support -- gcd, lcm, primality testing
- Readable syntax
- Support for exact fractions and relevant operations
- Linear algebra -- matrix multiplication/exponentiation, modular matrix multiplication/exponentiation, matrix solution/inversion, dot product

Nice to have:

- Small size in kB
- Support for transcendental operations (sin, cos, tan, exp, etc.)